# Ionic3 Lazy-Loading navCtrl.pop alternative

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, lazy-loading

I am using ionic3's Lazy-Loading for my app.
Logging in works fine with lazy-loading as it loads the components as you need them, however the problem comes in when I try LogOut.
OnLogOut I tried to use navCtrl.pop like I used to do in Ionic 2.

```
logout() {
  this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  this.navCtrl.pop();
}
```

Which causes the following runtime error:

> Runtime Error: Navigation stack needs at least one root page

I am guessing that there is no underlying page on the stack, due to lazy loading ? 
Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Yes exactly lazy loading uses only one page(component) at one time... It's lazy loading so you simply call the logout page as usual... this.navCtrl.push('pageName')

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot('LoginPage');
```

If you use navCtrl.push, you will endup getting a back button on the login page. Therfore use setRoot()

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Loading doesn't maintain a stack & that is why you are getting this error `Runtime Error: Navigation stack needs at least one root page`

Try

```
logout() {
  this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage'); //Coming back to Login Page after logging out
}
```